# Delete unknown number of lines from * until blank line

Tags: sed

I've been using this forum, so I just now joined!  I have seen similar questions but nothing has worked so far (mostly using sed). I want to find each instance of an asterisk (*) in a file and delete it and everything after it until a blank line is reached. For example:

```
*252
253
254
255
(blank line here)
```

OR

```
*261
265
(blank line here)
```

Each block of data will vary in length. Then I want to have output go to a new file. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly hasn't worked so far ? This is really simple...

Comment: sed '/"*"/,/" "/{/" "/ s/.*/" "/; t; d}'DIDtemp2 >DIDtemp1

Comment: that's the most recent that didn't work. I based that on another response in here. I've deleted the other two already.

Comment: Since you've been using "this forum" you know this kind of stuff should be part of your question and not a comment...

Comment: Sorry... still learning!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To delete from a line containing `*` to the next empty line, use:

```
sed '/[*]/,/^$/d' filename
```

Notes:

1. Since `*` is a regex-active character and we only want to match a literal `*`, we need to escape the `*`. This could be done as `\*` or, as shown above, `[*]`.
2. To match an empty line, we need a line with no characters between its beginning, denoted `^`, and its end, denoted `$`.  Thus `^$` matches an empty line.
3. `/[*]/,/^$/` is a range: it matches a group of lines that start with a line containing `*` and end with an empty line.
4. `d` tells sed to delete any line in the range.

The above produces output to stdout.  To change a file in place, use:

```
sed -i.bak '/[*]/,/^$/d' filename
```

#### Example

Consider this sample file:

```
$ cat filename
*252
253
254
255

OR
*261
265

end
```

This produces:

```
$ sed '/[*]/,/^$/d' filename
OR
end
```